# How do I make my Collapse component working in reactjs app?

Tags: html, reactjs, reactstrap

Check out the code below, I used "Collapse" component of reactstrap but its not working as it should be.
What changes should I make to make this working.

```
import { Component } from "react";
import React from "react";
import { Collapse, Navbar } from "reactstrap";
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }
  show() {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={() => this.show()}>Show</button>
        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.open} navbar>
          <Navbar>hello</Navbar>
        </Collapse>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default Main;
```

Comment: Have you tried binding the show() method to the class?

Comment: I am using arrow function here so no need to bind method here. @CyberMessiah

Comment: What if you try this portion inside your show() method: this.setState(prevState => ({ open: !prevState.open }));

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem originates in your show method since this.state is updated asynchronously. The right syntax should be the following:

```
show() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ open: !prevState.open}));
}
```

You may refer to this documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Thats not working. Check out the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-currying-4pvyd?file=/src/Main.js)

Comment: You have to import somewhere the Main component either in App or in some other. In the demo you haven't done it.